# How do I select a bone in a downloaded Blender skeleton and edit it?

Tags: rigging, bones

I have downloaded a blender skeleton that I would like to make more realistic, e.g. separate the two pelvic bones that he has, into the 6 real bones.  Brand new to Blender, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the armature to select it, and go into edit mode. Right click on the bone you want to divide into smaller bones and press <kbd>W</kbd> and choose *subdivide*. On the left panel (press <kbd>T</kbd> to show it if it's hidden) change the number of cuts from 1 to 6.